# Add other column (time) to DISTINCT rows

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I am selecting unique rows with

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    LogContent
FROM   
    [WebAppLog] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE  
    LogName = 'frontendErrorLog'
```

But how to pair result with other column? I want to select unique `LogName` and assign it corresponding earliest `LogTime` just like in:

```
SELECT 
    LogTime, LogContent 
FROM   
    [WebAppLog] WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE  
    LogName = 'frontendErrorLog'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ultra

Will a grouping work for you, like this.

```
SELECT  LogContent,MAX(LogTime) LogTime
FROM    [WebAppLog] WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE   LogName = 'frontendErrorLog'
GROUP   BY LogContent
```

Comment: Is this including DISTINCT?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT LogTime, LogContent, 
           rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LogContent ORDER BY LogTime ASC)
    FROM [WebAppLog] WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE LogName = 'frontendErrorLog'
)
SELECT LogTime, LogContent FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```